# Motor-powered gyroscope's precession speed

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rotational-kinematics, gyroscopes, precession

[image]

I was doing experiment about the gyroscope's precession speed and I made my own gyroscope, which is the one in the picture. It is the motor-powered gyroscope as I found out the one made with bearing provided friction so much and the rotation of the disk stopped quickly. I first balanced the gyroscope with the counter mass so that the system remains horizontally. Then, I added the supplementary mass to sea how's its motion changed.

However, what I noticed doing the experiment was the gyroscope's precession got faster and faster as it rotated 1st period, 2nd period, .. and goes on. This was almost the same no matter where the supplementary mass is positioned, close to the string or close to the counter mass. Do you think the physics of this result is because of the motor? As the motor kept provide the power?